# Confusion in Confidence Interval and Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, inference

Consider a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ where $\sigma^2 = 9$ and we draw 100 samples from this distribution. Now, we set up a hypothesis testing problem: $H_{0}:\mu = 0$ against $H_{a}:\mu \ne 0$. We reject null if $|mean| > K$ with 0.05 as the size of the test. It is required to obtain the $95$% confidence interval of $\mu$.

In this problem, I don't understand why have they provided us with all this extra information about hypothesis testing ($H_0$ and $H_a$) when the confident interval could be just computed by using the formula :

$\bar{X}_{n} \pm \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}*Z_{0.05}$

What is the use of this extra information about hypothesis testing when the CI could just be obtained without it? They also have provided four options to choose from:

1. $(-0.488, 0.688)$
2. $(-1.96, 1.96)$
3. $(0.422, 1.598)$
4. $(0.588, 1.96)$

EDIT.1 If I instead specify the problem as follows:

Consider a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ where $\sigma^2 = 9$ and we draw 100 samples from this distribution. It is required to obtain the $95$% confidence interval of $\mu$.

Here, I have omitted the hypothesis specification from the problem. Now, my doubt was that, we can form the confidence interval even without that information, then what was the need for that?

Comment: Please can you clarify which bit of the problem statement do you consider extra (and perhaps unnecessary as you seems to imply) information? The formula required $\sigma$ and $n$, which is given in the statement, and the formula is only applicable when the problem setting as specified in the question is specified.

Comment: Why is it so that formula is only applicable when the problem setting is specified as in it is specified? If I have $X$ following $N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$ and consider a sample of size $n$. Now, $\bar{X}_{n}$ follows normal $N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^{2}}{n})$ . If I have to make a CI of $\mu$ with size $100(1-\alpha)$% then I can just write: $P(|\frac{\bar{X}_{n}-\mu}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}}}| <k) = 1-\alpha$. From here, I can use adjust the terms for $\mu$ to get an interval with probability $100(1-\alpha)$%. Here, I have never used the hypothesis specification. This probability is true in general

Comment: 1) to let you know that it is a two-sided equal tail test and 2) they want you to use $K$ in your answer.

Comment: Alright, if I use their rejection region as a starting point to form the CI, then here is what I will get: $ P(| \bar{X}_{n} | >K | H_{0}) = \alpha $ which implies $ P(| \bar{X}_{n} | <=K | H_{0}) = 1-\alpha $. Using this probability, i can possibly make the CI for $\mu$. But if you notice, then this in this probability statement under null hypotheis, the left hand side of inequality does not depend on $\mu$ under null. How am i supposed to form the CI for $\mu$ in this case?

Comment: In your second option, I don't know $\bar{X}$. I think you need either this or a null hypothesis in order to determine where to center your CI. Without having $\mu = 0$ or $\bar{X}$, where would you center your CI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found out the correct Approach for this problem. First, I can compute the width of the interval which will be $\frac{2\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} Z_{0.025}$. It will be equal to $1.176$ after taking the value of $Z_{0.025} = 1.96$.

Now, out of the four options given, Only one of the option has this limit. Hence, that would be an answer. I also understood why the hypothesis specification was necessary. It was because usually the rejection region is the complement of the confidence interval which means the value of $\mu$ under the null hypothesis cannot be in the interval. Hence, First two options where we have 0 inside the interval cannot be the option. This is just an additional information. This problem just could have been solved by obtaining width of the interval.